# Is it okay to change application configuration from inside a Unit Test?

Tags: php, unit-testing, codeigniter

I'm writing a library for CodeIgniter, and when writing tests, I need to check what happens when the library's or CodeIgniter's configuration is changed to various options I am making available.

The simplest way out appears to be using the [Config class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html) to get and set config variables on the fly, and it does solve the problem. I just don't like the look of that solution.

What are the equivalents to this in other languages/frameworks, what are the potential problems that might be faced, and how to avoid all this altogether?

Comment: If your test passes or fails depending on factors the tested code doesn't control, by definition that's not really a *unit* test...

Comment: Indeed... maybe I should I write the tests such that particular tests get skipped when so-and-so config option is set as such-and-such.

Comment: Ideally, you'd redo things so that that stuff that can change, can be switched out at will for test objects with known behaviors.  Besides making testing more reliable by isolating the tested code from the rest of the app, it'd also go a long way toward improving the code's modularity as a result (or, cause?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what your testing but I know that when I test (and this has been the policy of most places I've worked, well the ones that have their stuff together) I try to make sure all of my input is controlled and validated, as in I know exactly what is going and what should come out.

So for your specific case, if possible I would generate a "Testing" config file and use that so that you know for sure exactly what is going and what should be coming out.

EDIT: To answer your question more specifically, in my opinion I would say it is not okay to change configuration values on the fly.

Why? Because what if something breaks and you don't catch it and suddenly your configuration values are changed and get deployed to production and...*BOOM* meltdown. Obviously a worse case scenario but still